# Can I define and setup a context manager before using with

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using requests to create a `requests.Session` and set it up inside a function:

```
def create_web_session(cookie=None):
    s = requests.Session()
    if cookie is not None:
        s.cookies.set("my_cookie_name", cookie)
    return s
```

Sessions can be used as context managers. Can I use the function that returns the session (above) in a `with` statement?

```
with create_web_session("my_cookie_value") as s:
     s.get(...)
```

Or would I have to change the function that instead takes a session and sets it up inside the context manager:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    setup_web_session(s, "my_cookie_value")
    s.get(...)
```

Running the former seemed to work however my unit tests failed which is why I asked this question. I am patching the `create_web_session` and upon testing the `s.get(...)` I am asserting that my mock gets called with `.get()` however it seems to be `session_mock.__enter__()` that is calling it. Is this expected behavior?

Here is an example:

```
# Function
def my_function():
    s = create_web_session()
    s.get("https://google.com")
    s.close()

# Test
@patch("foo.bar.create_web_session")
def test_my_function(self, mock_create_web_session):
    my_function()
    mock_create_web_session.assert_called_once()
    mock_create_web_session.return_value.get.assert_called_once()
    mock_create_web_session.return_value.close.assert_called_once()
```

Once I change the function to use context managers:

```
def my_function():
    with create_web_session() as s:
        s.get("https://google.com")
```

The test fails with:
`Expected 'get' to have been called once. Called 0 times.`

Comment: Have you tried? What happened?

Comment: @glibdud It did seem to work however my unit tests failed leading me to ask this question. I am patching the `create_web_session` and upon testing the `s.get(...)` I am asserting that my mock gets called with `.get()` however it seems to be `session_mock.__enter__()` that is calling it. I will add this to the question :)

Comment: This should be fine. I don't quite understand the last paragraph. Can you show us the unit testing code and the expected/actual results? You should expect that the methods `__enter__`, `get`, and `__exit__` will be called on the session (or its mock), in that order.

Comment: @AlexHall I added this to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create_web_session` is fine. The problem in the test is that while `requests.Session.__enter__` simply returns back the same session, all methods on a mock return a fresh mock object. We can tell the mock to behave how we want and get a working test case like so:

```
def test_my_function(self, mock_create_web_session):
    session = mock_create_web_session.return_value
    session.__enter__.return_value = session

    my_function()

    mock_create_web_session.assert_called_once()
    session.get.assert_called_once()
    session.__exit__.assert_called_once()
```

Note that I assert `__exit__` is called, not `close`, because the mock doesn't know anything about `close` or real sessions.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. In fact, looking at the source code of `requests.Session`, this is now obvious :)